# UWP NavigationView nested within ContentFrame

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm having an issue currently with creating a second NavigationView instance within my project. I have been using the AppUIBasics extensively whilst learning UWP and noticed that it has NavigationViews nested within Frames as per this example:

[image]

I have been unable to replicate this though.

My use case is as follows:

- I load the program, it creates the main NavView on the left hand side
- I click the settings AppBarButton that changes  the Main navigations view ContentFrame to the SettingsPage.xaml Page
- SettingsPage has a Top NavigationView that will allow me to flick between different settings but is currently not displaying on launch.

Id doesnt throw any syntax errors or XAML errors but Im not entirely sure what is going on
Ive selected what i believe is useful:

**MainPage navigation XAML**

```
<!-- Navigation view Variable decleration -->
    <NavigationView IsSettingsVisible="False" 
                        PaneTitle="Menu"                            
                        x:Name="NavView" 
                        Loaded="NavView_Loaded"
                        IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed" 
                        PaneDisplayMode="Left" 
                        PaneClosed="NavView_PaneClosed"
                        AlwaysShowHeader="True"        
                        SelectionChanged="NavView_SelectionChanged" Foreground="{StaticResource DefaultTextColour}">

        <!-- All navigation view Items nested within here -->
        <NavigationView.MenuItems>                

// Removed un-necessary menuitems here

        </NavigationView.MenuItems>

        <!-- Navigation pane footer -->
        <NavigationView.PaneFooter>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="AppBarButtons" Tag="AppBarButtonPanel" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=NavView, Path=IsPaneOpen}" Margin="16,0,16,0" Height="50"> 

// THIS IS THE NAVIGATION TO THE SETTINGS PAGE

                    <AppBarButton Icon="Setting" Margin="1, 2, 0, 0" Tag="Settings_Page" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="56.5" Height="40.5" ClickMode="Press" Click="SettingsButton_Click" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Budget Settings"/>       
                </StackPanel>               
            </StackPanel>
        </NavigationView.PaneFooter>

        <!-- Defining the ContentFrame Transition effect-->
        <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame">
```

**MainPage Navigation XAML (SettingsButton Only)**

```
// BUTTON CLICK HANDLERS HERE
        private void SettingsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(Content_Pages.SettingsPage));
            NavView.IsPaneOpen = false;
        }
```

**Settings_Page XAML**

```
  <Grid>      

        <muxcontrols:NavigationView PaneDisplayMode="Top" 
                    IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed" 
                    IsSettingsVisible="False" 
                    x:Name="SettingNavView" 
                    SelectionChanged="SettingNavView_SelectionChanged"
                    Foreground="{StaticResource DefaultTextColour}"                    
                    Grid.Row="0">
            <NavigationView.MenuItems>
                <NavigationViewItem Content="File Properties" x:Name="FileProperties" Tag="FileProperties_Page"/>
                <NavigationViewItem Content="UI Customisation" x:Name="UICustomisation" Tag="UICustomisation_Page"/>
            </NavigationView.MenuItems>

        </muxcontrols:NavigationView>

        <Frame x:Name="SettingsContent"/>

    </Grid>
```

**SettingsPage CodeBehind:**

```
public sealed partial class SettingsPage : Page
    {
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            // Navigate to the Home Page
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(Content_Pages.SettingsPageContent.FileProperties_Page));
        }

        private void SettingNavView_SelectionChanged(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewSelectionChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            NavigationViewItem item = args.SelectedItem as NavigationViewItem;

            if(item != null)
            {
                switch (item.Tag.ToString())
                {
                    case "FileProperties_Page":
                        SettingsContent.Navigate(typeof(Content_Pages.SettingsPageContent.FileProperties_Page));
                        break;
                    case "UICustomisation_Page":
                        SettingsContent.Navigate(typeof(Content_Pages.SettingsPageContent.UICustomisation_Page));
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If i have excluded to much information, please let me know. I will add it back in. If anything needs further clarification, please let me know.

Comment: I will recommend you to use the Pivot within the settings page for your different pages, it will be much simpler for you to implement and even this is the standard way of showing multiple items in settings in uwp apps.

Comment: Okay, Pivot was the original way i had this going but the documentation stated it may be best to use NavigationView (It also looks better IMO) The resource i was using is this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/pivot#create-a-pivot-control

Comment: NavigationView is recommended for basic top navigation , especially when you have a lot of NavigationItems, but if you have a few items or you need nested navigation in a page it is best to use Pivot, because it creates balance and a clear difference tht it is not a top level navigation but a nested one.

Comment: Amazing, thanks for the input on this :) Ill go back to the Pivot